# How do I claim US Tax Credits for Energy Efficiency?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

We bought a house last year and after the building was done my wife forced me to buy the blinds through the builder, claiming I wasn't going to buy any and put the up myself which I told her I would.

Anyhow, the builder said the blinds would fall under a credit on my tax return this year, but as I used Taxcut I haven't been able to find where I would put this credit in.  There is a section where they ask about energy credit type things, but they ask me if I have some weird tax form.  Where would I put in this credit?  Do I need to ask the builder for some tax form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.houselogic.com/home-advice/windows-doors/energy-efficient-window-coverings/) at HomeLogic describes the basics on what you can claim. In essence:

- You are probably good for a $500 credit;
- Make sure you have the certifications from the builder but no need to submit them;
- You will need 5695 from the IRS

Note that the law does not explicitly include treatments like blinds, but as the link discusses, it doesn't exclude them either. Submit your claim and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a heat pump installed last year. The company provided a certificate certifying that the model I purchased met the requirements for the tax credit.

Based on a quick scan of several companies it appears that your window treatments may fall under insulation. You will need to get a certificate from the builder. You also may need a receipt to show your cost.

The credit for the heat pump was not as easy to find as I thought. I don't know how easy it is to find the one for insulation. One site did mention [IRS tax form 5695](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f5695.pdf).